# What about wearing hats in Winter Bash 2013?

Tags: discussion

Last year's [Winter Bash 2012](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) let us discover and wear hats all over the site during the season's holidays. Now a new winter approaches, and we will have the opportunity to participate in the Winter Bash 2013 too.

During the seasons (from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014) we will be able to discover and wear funny hats by using our site in special ways, such as voting, posting on meta, editing posts to be better, and even chatting. The achievements vary, and we may be able to collect hats as we participate. After 3 January all will be back to normal.

Of course there also will be a *"I hate hats"* option for any user who does not want to wear a hat.

Should we as a community participate? Please vote on the answers below, the option with most votes upon shall win.

Comment: For those who are new to the site I gave a link to images from the [Winter Bash 2012](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) to get the idea. You can **optionally** let your avatar wear a "hat" (or another cool item) after accomplishing certain tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes

let us participate in the Winter Bash 2013.

Comment: Those hats don't make sense. They disturb our serious target with gaga and gugu. Instead of hard working on our language peoplel will have fun without reason, and only give good answers for earning childish hats. Let's vote yes.

Comment: @userunknown Feel free to vote "no"...

Answer (score 5):

## ?

I don't care about participating or not.

Answer (score 0):

## No

we should not participate in the Winter Bash 2013.